# How to fetch data in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to do something like `PDOStatement::fetchAll` with Eloquent? I need to get 3 fields from the db, but when i use `get` it returns object with some other data and i need to loop it to get my data.

Comment: Your query is only returning one row ?

Comment: @YellowBird, nope, it returns about 5-10 rows.

Comment: And what are you trying to do exactly ? retrieving 3 fields per row ? Could you show us some code ?

Comment: @YellowBird yep, post id, name, description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toArray()` with `select()` and `get()` :

```
$data = Model::where(YOUR_WHERE_CLAUSE)->select('post_id', 'name', 'description)->get()->toArray();
```

It will return you an associative array with the data you want. **But** you'll still have to loop through rows to get the data for each row the query has returned.